# INSERT INTO causing nulls in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to concatenate two columns and add a comma and space between them in SQL Server 2014.

Here's the code I'm using (redacting the table name for privacy reasons)

```
INSERT INTO Table (EntityName)
    SELECT CONCAT(MailingLine1, ', ', MailingState) 
    FROM Table
```

This is concatenating the strings correctly, but in the process, it's causing all other columns and all other rows to read as NULL and wipes the data from the table.

There are roughly 30 columns that already have data within them

Any thoughts?

Comment: well......yeah, you aren't giving the other columns any values in your insert, so it's assigning the default (which in this case is `NULL`)

Comment: `INERT INTO table (EntityName) VALUES ("value1")`

Comment: Can you show your schema and sample data?

Comment: Read what @Lamak said

Comment: It's going to continue giving you null because you only have it as `Insert into Table (EntityName)` when it should be `Insert into Table (EntityName) values ("insert_value")`

Comment: OP, are you trying to `UPDATE` a column based on 2 other columns?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 No, that's not the problem. Op needs to assign values to the other columns of his table: `INSERT INTO dbo.Table(Column1, Column2, Column3) SELECT SomeExpression1, SomeExpression2, SomeExpression3 FROM dbo.Table1`

Comment: @Lamak i agree with that

Comment: @Hadi That, or op wants an `UPDATE`

Comment: @Lamak i think you're right he is not looking to insert new rows, but he can also use computed column *(based on his needs he have to decide `UPDATE` or `Computed column`)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to add a new column with this function `CONCAT(MailingLine1, ', ', MailingState)` so you can use a computed column

```
--if [EnityName]  already exists in the table you have to drop it first
alter table TABLE
drop column [EntityName]

alter table TABLE
add [EntityName] as CONCAT(MailingLine1, ', ', MailingState)
```

If you don't want to add a computed column you can follow @GordonLinoff answer *(use UPDATE command)*

---

Else, If you are looking to insert new rows not to update rows, the issue is that you are only inserting values in `EntityName` column and ignoring all other columns, you can assign values as the following *(assuming you have 3 columns)*

```
Insert into Table (EntityName,EntityName2,EntityName3)

SELECT CONCAT(MailingLine1, ', ', MailingState),Value1,Value2 FROM Table
```

Where `Value1,Value2` can be columns from the table, or fixed value *i.e. `'John'`*

Comment: @Lamak a ok check it out now

Comment: There's roughly 30 columns

Comment: @LexJamesRussell you have to list them all, you can use the script as function to generate queries faster

Comment: Just `right click on the table -> script as -> Insert TO`

Comment: @LexJamesRussell since you are new to stackoverflow i think it is good to visit the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about this site and get your first "informed" badge.

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for the other volums, a not NULL value. (See example)

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD DEFAULT {dafault_value} FOR {column_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update Table
    set EntityName = CONCAT(MailingLine1, ', ', MailingState);
```

Comment: Agreed. Since OP is pulling from the same table name.